# How to utilize matrix math for neighbour processing in HLSL?

Tags: matrix, gpu, vectorization, hlsl, fragment-shader

I'm trying to do neighbour processing on GPU with HLSL, and I'm wondering if there is a way to load an array of neigbour samples at once and not just one sample, so that I can utilize matrix math instead of for loops.

My current implementation, using SampleLevel function is something like:

`float3 pixel = inputTex.SampleLevel(sampleState, uv + uvOffset, 0.0, 0.0);`

Instead, I'd like to load more than one sample at a time, but I haven't found an API for that. Or if my approach for this is totally wrong, please let me know how else to go about utilizing vectorization and matrix math in HLSL. Thanks for any advice and have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know max you can get from single texture access is float4.

Your options are (Assuming you only need 4 neighboring values):

- Calling 4 Load methods (requires texel integer coordinate, and not UV).
- Calling 4 Sample methods using point sampler (requires offseting UV by 0.5/textureSize, so your samples would be (u - offset, v - offset), (u + offset, v - offset), (u - offset, v + offset), (u + offset, v + offset))
- If your texture is single channel (Or if you only need red channel), you can use Gather - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/dx-graphics-hlsl-to-gather